# How to trim the Node field is rendered in page.html.twig?

Tags: 8

I have rendered the node(custom) field in page.html.twig. Custom field is a summary text field.

And now, I want to trim the text field.

I have tried the below code,

```
{% set summary = node.field_custom|render|striptags %}
{{ summary|length > 10 ? summary|slice(0, 10) ~ '...' : summary }}
```

This is not working in page.html.twig. But its working only in the node.html.twig.

Showing error like,

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "Object of type Drupal\\Core\\Field\\FieldItemList cannot be printed."
```

How do I trim the summary field which is rendered in page.html.twig.

Please help me to solve this ?

**NOTE: I could not control it in the managed Display section. If the reduce the number in the Trim character section, its not working.**

Comment: Why not use the SmartTrim module? Anyway, try rendering content.field_custom instead of node object.

Comment: content.field_custom is only work in node.html.twig. If we use the field in page.html.twig, then we should render like node.field_custom. And I am looking for code instead of using module for simple thing

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking now, rendering from page template is different than node.

Comment: Besides, SmartTrim provides field formatting enhancements to do exactly what you're asking for any text field, instead of coding around each instance in a template.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue on our site recently. You are trying to print a [FieldItemList](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemList.php/class/FieldItemList/8.2.x), which has no [__toString function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172261/where-and-why-do-we-use-tostring-in-php), and therefore cannot be implicitly converted to a string, as you are trying to do.

In your case, `node.field_custom` appears to be a FieldItemList. I know, you thought it was just a string value from a field -- but it's not. Drupal treats ALL fields as FieldItemLists in the API, even in cases where the field can't possibly contain more than one value. (This presumably makes the implementation cleaner.)

---

One quick solution to your problem, although this is a bit messy, is to call [`first()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21Plugin%21DataType%21ItemList.php/function/ItemList%3A%3Afirst/8.2.x), to get a TypedDataInterface, [`getValue()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemList.php/function/FieldItemList%3A%3AgetValue/8.2.x), which returns an associative array, and `['value']`, in your Twig template, like so:

```
node.field_custom.first().getValue()['value']
```

That should return a string. However, for those functions to be accessible in a Twig template, you need to enable them in `settings.php` and clear the system cache. Here's what worked for us:

```
$settings['twig_sandbox_whitelisted_methods'] = [
        'first',
        '__toString',
        'bundle',
        'id',
        'label',
];
```

But in your case, you may have to whitelist more methods to get what you want.

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates) is some more information on discovering variables in Twig templates.

Comment: The following should also work `node.field_custom.0.value`

Comment: or `node.field_custom.value`. But you get the raw database value. This doesn't work for formatted text fields. Only for plain text fields.

Answer (score 0):

This below code will trim the node field_custom in page.html.twig. This will also clean the html raw values.

```
{% set summary = node.field_custom.value|render|striptags %}
{{ summary|length > 10 ? summary|slice(0, 10) ~ '...' : summary }}
```

But If the summary text has an image, Alternative text will be shown instead of image.